# Dynamic row in el-table Vue JS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, html-table, row, element-ui

I'm learning Vue JS. I'm using el-table to display my data as follows:

[el-table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3AGV.png)

Basically, I'm creating a function for a button's clicking event that contains parameter using properties of the row in the table (scope.row.id) in the code:

```js
<el-table-column align="center" prop="id" label="Chức năng" width="150">
    <template slot-scope="scope">
      <el-button
        type="primary"
        icon="el-icon-switch-button"
        @click="searchImportForm(scope.row.id)"
      ></el-button>
    </template>
</el-table-column>
```

Normally it works fine. However, I've recently added a new feature to the table which is the "search" feature. There is a new text box for the user to input a keyword and the table returns all the information containing that keyword.

Now, when I press the button, the function does not work anymore. And my problem is that the error tells "Cannot read property "id" of undefined".

Does anyone how to handle with dynamic data table like this ??

Update: Here is the full code of my problem

```html
<template>
  <div class="app-container">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <div class="importListHeader">
      <!-- <button @click="getImportData">Lấy dữ liệu</button> -->

      <div class="importList-header-box-boxID">
        <div>Mã thùng</div>
        <el-input v-model="searchByUser.boxID" placeholder="Nhập mã" class="importListBoxID" />
      </div>

      <div class="importList-header-box-productList">
        <div>Tên SP</div>
        <div class="importListMultiselect">
          <multiselect
            placeholder="Chọn sản phẩm"
            v-model="searchByUser.productName"
            :options="productOptions"
            label="name"
          ></multiselect>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="importList-header-box-supplier">
        <div>Tên xưởng</div>
        <el-input v-model="searchByUser.keyword" placeholder="Nhập tên xưởng" class="importListSupplier" />
      </div>

      <div class="importList-header-box-fromDate">
        <div>Từ ngày</div>
        <el-input
          id="importListFromDate"
          v-model="searchByUser.firstDate"
          placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"
          class="inputBox"
        />
      </div>

      <div class="importList-header-box-toDate">
        <div>Đến ngày</div>
        <el-input
          id="importListToDate"
          v-model="searchByUser.lastDate"
          placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"
          class="inputBox"
        />
      </div>

      <div class="importList-header-box">
        <el-button
          class="buttonImportList"
          type="success"
          @click="submitSearchImportInfo"
          icon="el-icon-search"
        ></el-button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <el-table ref="singleTable" :data="filteredLists" border fit highlight-current-row>
      <el-table-column align="center" label="#" width="55" prop="id"></el-table-column>

      <el-table-column align="center" label="Xưởng SX" width="200" prop="supplier"></el-table-column>

      <el-table-column align="center" label="Ngày nhập kho" width="150" prop="date"></el-table-column>

      <el-table-column align="center" label="Trạng thái" width="150">
        <template slot-scope="scope">
          <h3
            v-if="scope.row.status == 'Chưa hoàn thành' "
            style="background-color: #e8e8e8;  border-radius: 8px; font-size: 14px"
          >{{ scope.row.status }}</h3>

          <h3
            v-if="scope.row.status == 'Hoàn thành' "
            style="background-color: #67c23a;  border-radius: 8px; font-size: 14px"
          >{{ scope.row.status }}</h3>
        </template>
      </el-table-column>

      <!--
      <el-table-column class-name="status-col" label="Status" width="110" align="center">
        <template slot-scope="scope">
          <el-tag :type="scope.row.status | statusFilter">{{ scope.row.status }}</el-tag>
        </template>
 
      </el-table-column>
      -->
      <el-table-column align="center" prop="id" label="Chức năng" width="150">
        <template slot-scope="scope">
          <el-button
            type="primary"
            icon="el-icon-switch-button"
            @click="searchImportForm(scope.row.id)"
          ></el-button>
        </template>
      </el-table-column>

      <el-table-column align="center" label="Người tạo phiếu" width="180">
        <template slot-scope="scope">
          <el-tag id="importListCreate">{{ scope.row.create_user }}</el-tag>
        </template>
      </el-table-column>

      <el-table-column align="center" label="Người thực hiện" width="180">\
        <template slot-scope="scope">
          <el-tag id="importListConfirm">{{ scope.row.confirm_user }}</el-tag>
        </template>
      </el-table-column>

      <el-table-column align="center" label="Ghi chú" prop="description"></el-table-column>
    </el-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect'

export default {
  filters: {
    statusFilter(status) {
      const statusMap = {
        published: 'success',
        draft: 'gray',
        deleted: 'danger'
      }
      return statusMap[status]
    }
  },

  data() {
    return {
      searchByUser: {
        keyword: '',
        firstDate: '',
        lastDate: '',
        boxID: '',
        productName: ''
      },

      lists: [
        // {
        //   id: '',
        //   supplier: '',
        //   date: '',
        //   status: ''
        // }
      ],
      productOptions: [{}],

      startDate: '00-00-0000',
      endDate: '31-12-3000'
    }
  },

  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    axios
      .post('http://192.168.1.93:3000/displayAllInPaper')
      // axios.post('http://192.168.1.93:3000/displayAllInPaper')
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
        next(vm => {
          for (var i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++) {
            vm.lists.push({
              id: res.data[i].id,
              supplier: res.data[i].supplier,
              date: res.data[i].created_at,
              status:
                res.data[i].cur_status == 'p'
                  ? 'Chưa hoàn thành'
                  : 'Hoàn thành',
              description: res.data[i].paper_desc,
              create_user: res.data[i].create_user,
              confirm_user: res.data[i].confirm_user
            })
          }

          axios.post('http://192.168.1.93:3000/getProductType').then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            for (var i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++) {
              vm.productOptions.push({
                name: res.data[i].cur_name
              })
            }
          })
        })
      })
  },

  methods: {
    submitSearchImportInfo() {
      axios
        .post('http://192.168.1.93:3000/searchInPaperWithProduct', {
          productID: this.searchByUser.boxID,
          productName: this.searchByUser.productName
        })
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res)
          this.lists.splice(0, this.lists.length)
          for (var i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++) {
            this.lists.push({
              id: res.data[i].id,
              supplier: res.data[i].supplier,
              date: res.data[i].created_at,
              status:
                res.data[i].cur_status == 'p' ? 'Chưa hoàn thành' : 'Hoàn thành'
            })
          }
        })
    },

    setCurrentRow(row) {
      this.$refs.singleTable.setCurrentRow(row)
    },

    searchImportForm(id_par) {
      this.$store.state.products.splice(0, this.$store.state.products.length)
      this.$store.state.inPaperID = this.filteredLists[id_par - 1].id
      axios
        .post(
          'http://192.168.1.93:3000/getDetailInPaper',
          this.filteredLists[id_par - 1]
        )
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res)
          for (var i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++) {
            this.$store.state.products.push({
              productID: res.data[i].id,
              cur_name: res.data[i].cur_name,
              perbox: res.data[i].perbox,
              box_amount: res.data[i].box_amount,
              scan_number: res.data[i].scan_number
            })
          }
        })
      this.$router.push({ path: '/import/details' })
    },

    filteredByName(lists) {
      return lists.filter(list =>
        list.supplier.match(this.searchByUser.keyword)
      )
    },

    localizeDate(date) {
      if (!date || !date.includes('/')) return date
      const [dd, mm, yyyy] = date.split('/')
      return (date = `${yyyy}-${mm}-${dd}`)
    },

    convertDate(date) {
      const [yyyy, mm, dd] = date.split('-')
      var newDate = `${yyyy}${mm}${dd}`
      var newDate2 = parseInt(newDate)
      return (date = newDate2)
    },

    filteredByDateRange(lists) {
      if (this.searchByUser.firstDate != '') {
        this.startDate = this.searchByUser.firstDate
      }
      if (this.searchByUser.lastDate != '') {
        this.endDate = this.searchByUser.lastDate
      }
      return lists.filter(list =>
        this.convertDate(list.date) >=
          this.convertDate(this.localizeDate(this.startDate)) &&
        this.convertDate(list.date) <=
          this.convertDate(this.localizeDate(this.endDate))
          ? list
          : ''
      )
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredLists: function() {
      // return this.filteredByDateRange(this.lists)
      if (
        this.searchByUser.keyword == '' &&
        this.searchByUser.firstDate == '' &&
        this.searchByUser.lastDate == ''
      ) {
        return this.filteredByName(this.lists)
      }

      if (
        this.searchByUser.keyword != '' &&
        this.searchByUser.firstDate == '' &&
        this.searchByUser.lastDate == ''
      ) {
        return this.filteredByName(this.lists)
      }

      if (
        this.searchByUser.keyword == '' &&
        (this.searchByUser.firstDate != '' || this.searchByUser.lastDate != '')
      ) {
        return this.filteredByDateRange(this.lists)
      }

      if (
        this.searchByUser.keyword != '' &&
        (this.searchByUser.firstDate != '' || this.searchByUser.lastDate != '')
      ) {
        return this.filteredByDateRange(this.filteredByName(this.lists))
      }
    }
  },

  components: {
    Multiselect
  }
}
</script>

<style src="vue-multiselect/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css"></style>

<style>
.importListHeader {
  max-width: 96%;
  display: flex;
  text-align: left;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


.inputBox {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
}
.el-dropdown-menu {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.el-dropdown-link {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.importListMultiselect .multiselect__tags {
  min-height: 40px;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 40px 0 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 0.5px solid #e8e8e8;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 320px;
}

.importListMultiselect .multiselect {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
  min-height: 40px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #35495e;
}

#importListFromDate {
  width: 200px;
}

#importListToDate {
  width: 200px;
}

.buttonImportList {
  position: absolute;
  top: 39px;
}
.el-icon-arrow-down {
  font-size: 8px;
}
.el-dropdown {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.importListBoxID {
  max-width: 210px;
}

.importList-header-box-boxID {
  max-width: 200px;
}

.importList-header-box-productList {
  max-width: 320px;
}

.importList-header-box-supplier {
  max-width: 250px;
}

.importList-header-box-fromDate {
  max-width: 200px;
}

.importList-header-box-toDate {
  max-width: 200px;
}

#importListCreate {
  font-size: 15px;
}

#importListConfirm {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #35495e;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-style: none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I think the error is in this method - searchImportForm(scope.row.id). You can add the code of this method and data - scope.row

Comment: Well, I don't think that's the problem but worth to have a try though. I've just uploaded my code in the post for your information.

Comment: Are you sure that you have value in `res.data[i]`? (`productID: res.data[i].id`). make sure that error does not correspond to this line of code.